# Is it possible to install and run Google Chrome without root access?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, root, selenium

Need to install Google Chrome on a Linux server without having root access. Chrome is needed in order to run Selenium webdirver tests with google chrome. Would this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Chrome is pretty portable between computers,
since it is entirely self-contained in `/opt/google/chrome/`.

Just copy that directory from somewhere else and you can launch it from there.

Comment: Awesome looks like that is going to work, thanks! Copying that directory and pointing Selenium to the binary in the copied directory instead of the default location works!